# Cannot open include/source files for google test

Tags: googletest

> Using VS 2015 Community, MS Win10 64bit
>
> I am trying to use google test framework..

I'm doing everything as per the tutorial- (http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/google_unit_test_gtest.php) but there is still error as mentioned above.

- Added include statements
- trying to include gtest dir
- installed google test extensions (google test adapter and google test
  runner for VS)
  but error still exists.
  I am sure the files exist, I can view them.

Errors like: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory.

Can someone guide me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add the include and library folders to your project.

Comment: Added includes - I mean I add _googletest_ dir and _googletest/include_ dirs to project by their absolute path

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths instead? Using absolute paths is usually not a good idea - if you relocate your project directory for any reason suddendly your entire build breaks...

Comment: How can I use relative path when googletest dir is in much different place than my project? I have to build it as static library

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No, we switched to other testing framework.